# Refactor Controller using Extension method

Tags: c#, asp.net, controller

I have been following this video and at minute 40 they suggest using extension method to clean up repeatable code in controller actions:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h7TJ7eGeT7Q&t=693s

I have this piece of code which repeats in every Controller:

```
        var currentUserId = HttpContext.GetCurrentUserId();
        if (!currentUserId.HasValue)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
```

After this is executed a different logic is executed and it always returns status code Ok.

I have been trying to extract this in an Extension Method:

```
    public static IActionResult NotFoundOnEmptyUserId(this ControllerBase controllerBase)
    {
        var currentUserId = controllerBase.HttpContext.GetCurrentUserId();
        if (!currentUserId.HasValue)
        {
            return controllerBase.NotFound();
        }
    }
```

However, I do not know what to do with returning OK as the logic is different for every endpoint.

For example PostSearchFilter is this:

```
        var filter = await _agentService.SaveFilterByUserId(currentUserId.Value, request.FilterName, request.SearchFiltersToSaveJson, ipAddress);

        return this.Ok(filter);
```

and delete search filter is :

```
        await _agentService.DeleteUserSearchFilter(currentUserId.Value, filterId, ipAddress);

        return this.Ok();
```

They obviously depend on this currentUserId. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you looking for the `[Authorize]` attribute? Or a custom version thereof?

Comment: No, I am just looking for way to extract this repeatable code.

Comment: The way to do it won't be tidier than repeating it everywhere, since you'll just be checking for not `null` returned from `NotFoundOnEmptyUserId`. There is a way you could do it with `Func<IActionResult>` but I think that would probably make your code less readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to use middleware for this purpose. Something like this:

```
public class NotFoundMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public NotFoundMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (!context.GetCurrentUserId().HasValue)
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status404NotFound;
            context.Response.Headers.Clear();
            return;
        }

        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want `await _next(context)` in the case that you want to return 404?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar agree.